# Changing class of element by clicking on different element using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm sure this is simple but I can't seem to find a concrete example of this.

I'm trying to change the class **'ion-android-arrow-dropdown'** to **'ion-android-arrow-dropup'** and vice versa by clicking on the li element with class **'js--i'** using Javascript. There are multiple instances of this.

Do I have to loop through child elements?

## HTML

```
<li class="js--i"><a href="#" id="sub-menu--parent-1">About Us
<i class="ion-android-arrow-dropdown"></i></a>
```

## Javascript

```
function arrowToggle(up, down, icon) {

    [].forEach.call(
        icon,
        function(icon) {
            icon.addEventListener('click', function() {
                console.log('test');

                /* Something here */

            }, false);
        }
    );           

}

arrowToggle(arrowUp, arrowDown, iconArrow);
```

Comment: I edited the question to reflect that. `.js--i` does not control anything, its only used for js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The various DOM API selector functions work on nodes as well as on the document, so you can use icon.querySelector('i'), or something similar, in your `something here` block, to select the relevent element.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(function(li) {
  li.addEventListener('click', function() {
    li.querySelector('i').classList.toggle('ion-android-arrow-dropup');
  })
})
```

```css
.ion-android-arrow-dropdown {
display: inline-block;
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
background-color: red;
}

.ion-android-arrow-dropup {
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<li class="js--i"><a href="#" id="sub-menu--parent-1">About Us
<i class="ion-android-arrow-dropdown"></i></a></li>

<li class="js--i"><a href="#" id="sub-menu--parent-1">About Us
<i class="ion-android-arrow-dropdown"></i></a></li>

<li class="js--i"><a href="#" id="sub-menu--parent-1">About Us
<i class="ion-android-arrow-dropdown"></i></a></li>

<li class="js--i"><a href="#" id="sub-menu--parent-1">About Us
<i class="ion-android-arrow-dropdown"></i></a></li>
```

Comment: This works the best, any tips on how to go about doing the opposite once the class is changed. I tried an if else statement but it just seems to cancel itself out.

Comment: When an element switches between two states, it's usually easiest to toggle a class on and off rather than switching between two different classes. I usually like to have one default class that is always on the element and a toggle class that activates the other state. I've updated the snippet to demonstrate.

Comment: Nvm, I placed that in the other foreach I had. This works perfect, thanks!

Comment: Glad you figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Select element having `js--i` class, listen to click and toggle classes:

```
document.querySelector(".js--i").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelector("i").classList.toggle("ion-android-arrow-up");
    document.querySelector("i").classList.toggle("ion-android-arrow-dropdown");
});
```

Comment: this works, I did this before but must have removed the class first so nothing happened.

Comment: @Dandan642, I don't think this will work if there are multiple `.js--i` elements on the page, which I think you indicate there will be.